# When NOT signed it, ErrorException - Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\xampp\...\show-solo.blade.php)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

Good day to all, just want to ask about Laravel for learning students like me.

When signed in, I am able to visit this page:

```
Route::get('/posts/{id}', 'PostController@showById');
```

When I am logged out and try to visit that page again, I get the error mentioned, I wish to show posts even for guest, but not allow to compose a post if they are logged out.

Here is the showById():

```
public function showById($id)
{
    $post = Post::find($id);

    return view('show-solo', compact('post'));
}
```

Also the show-solo.blade.php

```
@extends('master')

@include('partials.nav-none')

@section('content')
    <div class="col-sm-8 blog-main">
        <div class="blog-post">

            @if ($flash = session('message'))
                <div class="alert alert-success flash-message" role="alert">
                    {{ $flash }}
                </div>
            @endif

            @if ( $post->user_id  == Auth::user()->id)
                <a href="/posts/{{ $post->id }}/delete">
                    <button class="btn-sm btn-warning post-btn" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Delete Post"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
                </a>
                <a href="/posts/{{ $post->id }}/edit">
                    <button class="btn-sm btn-primary post-btn" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Edit Post"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i></button>
                </a>
            @endif          

            <h2>Post number: {{ $post->id }}</h2>

            <h2 class="blog-post-title">
                <a class="title-link" href="/posts/{{ $post->id }}">{{ $post->title }}</a>
            </h2>

            <!-- {{ $post->created_at->toFormattedDateString() }} -->
            <p class="blog-post-meta">{{ $post->created_at->diffForHumans() }} by <a href="#">{{ $post->user->name }}</a></p>
            {{ $post->body }}

            <hr />

            @include('partials.error')

            @include('partials.post-comment')
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

If this helps, here is my routes:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('/posts', 'PostController@index')->name('home');

Route::get('/posts/create', 'PostController@showForm');

Route::get('/posts/{id}', 'PostController@showById');

Route::get('posts/{id}/edit', 'PostController@editPostForm');

Route::get('posts/{id}/delete', 'PostController@deletePost');

Route::post('/posts', 'PostController@store');

Route::post('/posts/{post}/comments', 'CommentController@store');

Route::get('posts/{id}/delete', 'CommentController@deleteComment');

Route::post('/save-post', 'PostController@savePost');



Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');



Route::get('/register-user', 'RegistrationController@create');

Route::post('/register-user', 'RegistrationController@store');





Route::get('/login-user', ['as' => '/login-user', 'uses' => 'SessionController@create']);

Route::post('/login-user', 'SessionController@store');

Route::get('/logout-user', 'SessionController@destroy');
```

Am I doing anything wrong? Why can't I access /posts/{id} even if I'm a guest? What does that "Trying to get property of non-object" message mean?

Please tell me if I should quote some codes here to help solve the issue.

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the error on the following line

```
@if ( $post->user_id  == Auth::user()->id)
```

in the view.

The reason you are getting an error on this line is that you are trying to access id of the authenticated user like so, `Auth::user()->id`. But there is no authenticated user. Thus, the `Auth::user()` call returns `null`. And you are trying to access `id` on `null`.

Try changing it to

```
@if ( $post->user_id  == @Auth::user()->id)
```

OR

```
@if(Auth::user())
    @if ( $post->user_id  == Auth::user()->id)
    ...
    @endif
@endif
```

Comment: This did the trick for me "@if ( $post->user_id  == @Auth::user()->id)", can I ask what has happened in my situation for additional info, I'm a bit stuck to what have happened?

Comment: See my updated answer. I hope that clears your doubts.

Comment: I accepted the answer, Don't know why it didn't push through. Thanks again.